# Python - best way to iterate over a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file with several "data blocks" in it, like this:

```
log20140109
value1 3.056
value2 1.045
value3 0.064
log20140209
value1 1.036
value2 4.565
value3 3.344
log20140209
value1 0.432
value2 5.834
value3 3.030
and so on...
```

The idea is to read the data from that text file and draw a graph where x-axis values are strings starting with log-prefix and those floats are on y-axis. Each value should be a line on that graph.

What would be the best approach for reading the values for plotting them to graph? I knew the basic stuff regarding lists and dictionaries, but I haven't found how to apply them in this case. Is there any other data object that could be used?

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. You mention something about an x-axis and values that start with `log` and in the example data the `log` lines are identical. So i don't really see why they are grouped 3 by 3 if they refer to the same `x`. Try to provide a better example of input and/or output, how you want to group those values.

Comment: In any case, most of these things can be easily solved using things like [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a suitable `key` function.

Comment: Sorry my bad - the last string should be log20140309. ie. each datablock has a unic "name".

Answer (score 3):

without going into something more flexible, you can get your data into a pandas Dataframe with:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('bla.txt') as f:
    x = f.read()
all_lines = x.split('\n')
log_names = all_lines[0::4]
value1 = [float(x.split(' ')[1]) for x in all_lines[1::4]]
value2 = [float(x.split(' ')[1]) for x in all_lines[2::4]]
value3 = [float(x.split(' ')[1]) for x in all_lines[3::4]]
df = pd.DataFrame([value1, value2, value3], columns=['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], index =log_names)
```

not following exactly how you want to plot, but pandas should be able to handle it.

```
df.plot()
```

gives you this as a start

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! The example graph is something what I am looking for. I'll to dig into that pandas DataFrame thing. :)